# trying to link my IBOutlet NSwindow and getting an invalid parameter

Tags: xcode, macos, iboutlet

I am quite new to Xcode and its interface and I think I have done something weird. I lost the IBOutlet between the `mainMenu.xib` and the `NSWindow` property `@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;`

I tried to reconnect but I think I do something wrong as I keep getting this error and the window doesn't appear any more:

> 2014-05-13 16:37:03.684 multiply[26375:303] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1265.19/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1637
>   2014-05-13 16:37:03.685 multiply[26375:303] Ignoring exception raised
>   in void run_cocoa_block(void *): Invalid parameter not satisfying:
>   aString != nil

I guess I control drag that to the wrong place but it doesn't look like and I find it hard to track all the dragging.
I am sure this is a beginner classic but I have been looking for quite a while before sending this question.

Comment: wait, is this iOS or Mac? `NSWindow` and `AppKit` are for mac but this is tagged iOS.

Comment: Oops...Beginner mistake here again! Wrong TAG this is for Mac not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling `setStringValue:` or something similar on a `NSTextField`  somewhere giving `nil` as an argument. Put a breakpoint on the exception and see if you are passing any `NSString` nil objects as arguments.